# How to prevent "error-too many connections" to the RDBMS for a website accepting user registration for large traffic?

Tags: mysql, web, rdbms

What improvements do I make to the website so that I can contain or scale in order to prevent "error - too many connections" to the RDBMS for higher traffic days ?

Answer (score 0):

This is often a symptom of not releasing your connections when you are done.